# How should I present an error message to iOS users?

Tags: ios, design, error-message

I'm working on an iOS 8 iPhone app and I'm looking for a way to present an error message to the user like `You're offline, please check your network settings.` that goes away after a few seconds.

What is a good way to do this and is there a Apple suggested design for that kind of messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android offers you the opportunity to use a Toast, iOS doesn't have such a feature. [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) actually tells you to serve people [an AlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJCIGIA) whenever you want to show an error occurred.

Comment: There is, however, a library for making iOS Toasts: [https://github.com/scalessec/Toast](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast)

Comment: Apple's guidelines suggest you only use a UIAlertView where the user can't do anything about the error - see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html. If you're considering a timed message and users can continue to interact with the app, it sounds like you might want something other than an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Apple must provide a visual clue if it cannot send a text message. Why not leverage that? Just googled (as I don't use an iPhone) and Apple uses an exclamation point.

[image]

See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204065